# Problems with an array of class containing generic members

Tags: java, generics

When I compile this code:

```
public class OuterClass<T>
{
    class InnerClass
    {
       T temp;
    }
    
    private InnerClass[] theArray;
    
    public OuterClass(int size){
       this.theArray = new InnerClass[size];
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
OuterClass.java:10: error: generic array creation
      this.theArray = new InnerClass[size];
```

So my **question #1** is: why is creating an array of InnerClass a problem?  After all, it's an array of objects, not of a generic type.

My **question #2** is: why does modifying the code (see below) resolve the problem?

```
public class OuterClass<T>
{
    class InnerClass<U>  //changed this line
    {
       T temp;
    }
    
    private InnerClass<T>[] theArray;  //changed this line
    
    public OuterClass(int size){
       this.theArray = new InnerClass[size];
  }
}
```

Comment: When adding `<T>` to InnerClass you have _two_ definitions.  Try replacing the T’s with T1 and T2.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about what type of array you are instantiating here. In the first case, it is a

```
OuterClass<T>.InnerClass[]
```

Note that this type is a parameterised type (`<T>`), and [you are not allowed to create arrays of parameterised types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays).

In the second case, since the declaration of `InnerClass` is parameterised, the name "`InnerClass`" actually refers to a [*raw type*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) (because you are not specifying the type arguments), and because it is a raw type, the type of array that you are creating becomes:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass[]
```

Note that `OuterClass` loses its type parameter too, because you are using a raw type. This is now *not* a parameterised type, so you are allowed to create such an array.

Comment: OK thanks, so the line `private InnerClass<T>[] theArray;` makes `theArray` have a type of `OuterClass<T>.InnerClass<T>[]`, but then when I do `this.theArray = new InnerClass[size];`, I'm instantiating the array with a raw type?

Comment: @HangingParens Yes, and it is possible to assign a value of type `OuterClass.InnerClass[]` to a variable of type `OuterClass<T>.InnerClass<T>[]`, which is why there is no error about the assignment statement.

Comment: OK good, so if I change `private InnerClass<T>[] theArray` to `private InnerClass[] theArray`, that would also work, because now I am assigning a raw type to a variable of a raw type?

Comment: @HangingParens Yes, but you should avoid using raw types, as said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: In [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/) it says `MyType.Inner inn` is raw.  From what we've said above, `MyType<Object>.Inner` would be parameterized, but if we change `class Inner { }` to `class Inner<U> { }`, then `MyType<Object>.Inner` would be raw?

Comment: @HangingParens I don't think `MyType<Object>.Inner` is a valid type at all...

Answer (score 0):

The following code would work as well:

```
public class OuterClass<T>
{
    class InnerClass<U>  //changed from T to U
    {
       U temp;
    }

    private InnerClass<T>[] theArray;

    public OuterClass(int size){
       this.theArray = new InnerClass[size];
  }
}
```

In the first case, T is not recognized as a type parameter in the inner class. In case 2, you have provided a type parameter that you have selected to also be T for the inner class, but in fact has nothing to do with the type parameter of the outer class.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question, thanks.